# QStringList vs list<shared_ptr<QString>> perfomance compare C++

Tags: c++, list, performance, qt, pointers

I would like to ask what is better to use in Qt ?

QStringList what is basically QList so I am saving whole objects to list....or use std::liststd::shared_ptr<QString> ?

This list is saved as class variable and i dont pass it as argument anywhere. There will be saved maybe 300 strings (paths to folders).

I would say its better to use std::list of pointers but maybe, there is any advantage to use QStringList in Qt.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, a `std::list` is a bad idea in most cases (see [here](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB-bdWKwXsU&feature=youtu.be&t=2672)). I would recommend using a `std::vector`, or a `QVector`, which is also [recommended](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html).

The performance difference between vectors and (linked) lists is large, I don't know about the difference between the C++ standard containers and their Qt counter parts.

That being said, if you do a lot of lookups, you might want to use a `std::unordered_set` instead...